# How to install CakePHP in MAMP

Tags: cakephp, mamp

can somebody pls tell me or give me some references on how to install CakePHP on MAMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a video: http://vimeo.com/5868753

There's numerous tutorials via Google search "cakephp mamp", did none work for you?